# Access database connection from UI Module in Tornado

Tags: python, mysql, database, tornado

How can I get access to the database connection in the UI Module? I'm using built-in wrapper for MySQL in Tornado.

My application is completely similar [this](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py)

Comment: self.handler.db works, but is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used self.handler.db. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Just map the module class, don't use a separated uimodule.py.
Like this:

```
class EntryModule(tornado.web.UIModule):
    def render(self, entry):
        return self.render_string('modules-entry.html', entry=entry)

settings = {
    "login_url": "/login",
    ui_modules={"Entry": EntryModule},
}

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", HomeHandler),
    (r"/entry/([0-9]+)", EntryHandler),
    ], **settings)
```

Notice : `ui_modules={"Entry": EntryModule}`